# User.Agent for GWT 2.6?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, user-agent

Which user.agent properties are available for GWT 2.6 I found:

```
gecko1_8, safari, ie10, ie8,ie9,opera
```

When you want to use ie8,ie9,opera you have to enable them with:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" values="ie8,ie9,opera" />
```

**Did I miss any user agent? Which permutation is used by IE11?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to `<extend-property>` for ie6 and opera, which are disabled by default (and will be removed in the next version).

IE11 uses the same permutation as Firefox, i.e. gecko1_8.

Comment: About IE11 using gecko1_8: I see, that it's implemented like this in the master branch, but will this also be in 2.6 (in 2.6 RC1, and in the release/2.6 branch, it still returns ie10)?

Comment: Which user agent is used by Chrome?

Comment: Chrome uses the safari permutation.

Comment: IE11 won't fallback as IE10 since it changed the `msie` part of the user agent string to `trident` 0 GWT won't pick it up. Unless it is pretending to be IE10, in which case all bets are off as to what it will *actually* behave as...

Comment: @ColinAlworth so what does it mean for IE11 is there no permutation?

Comment: There's no permutation specific to IE11, because IE11 behaves very similarly to Firefox… when in IE11 mode! If you switch to any other mode (using X-UA-Compatible or in F12 dev tools) then it'll pick the permutation for that version of IE that's being emulated.